# The lisp approach to packaging a library of reusable functions?

Tags: package, common-lisp, sbcl

I have 3 function and 2 macros I use in every project. I can imagine that this list will grow over time.

In other languages, id upload these functions to github in a single file. Then import it as a module into the folder i was working in.

Is there a better way to have reusable code easily accessble to multiple projects in lisp?

Thanks.

Note -- all my projects have `.asd` files. Not sure if that changes things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would define a `my-lib.asd` file in a place that can be found by ASDF and or Quicklisp, as said in the other answer `quicklisp/local-projects/my-lib` is a good candidate at first.

Then inside this directory, you define `my-lib.asd`:

```
(defsystem :my-lib
   :components ((:file "packages")
                (:file "xyz")
                (:file "abc")))
```

Add as many files as necessary, in the way that makes the most sense for your library. And when you call `(ql:quickload :my-lib)` it should work without error.

Once this step is done, you should be able to add `:my-lib` as a system dependency to any other project, for example:

```
(defsystem :project :depends-on (:alexandria :my-lib))
```

Then loading `:project` with Quicklisp will automatically load all its dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a library system: define an ASDF system containing these functions, install it wherever your other ASDF systems live, and make it a dependency of other systems which need it.

I do not understand the details of how ASDF searches for systems, but assuming you use Quicklisp then this problem can be finessed by simply placing the system anywhere under `<quicklisp>/local-projects/` as QL installs a searcher for ASDF which will look there.  Ensuring the modification date of that directory is newer than the `system-index.txt` file in it will cause that file to be recreated and hence the search index to be rebuilt the next time QL has to think about it.  You can also add new local projects locations to `ql:*local-project-directories*` although I never do that.

I have makefiles which install 'finished' versions of things into QL's local projects as described above but if you have a git repo per system then you can just clone the repo there.

(There are various other alternatives to this: I personally use something which generally bypasses ASDF for small modules, but the library system is a safe approach I think, which uses widely-used tools.)

Comment: I see. So then in the `.asd` file ill add something like `:components ((:file "package")
                     (:file "path/to/library")` -- is that right?

Comment: also, will the library have a different (in-package...) ?

Comment: @Vinn: no the *system* will depend on the library system.  You just add a `:depends-on (...)` clause at the top-level of the `defsystem` form the same way you would if you were depending on some third-party system.  Packages are mostly orthogonal to systems but I would certainly put the library system in its own package with its own exports, and then have the packages of systems which depend on it use that package.